# JavaScript 'inheritance': constructor property is not correct

Tags: javascript, constructor

Please help explain the following result (tested on Firefox 3.6). How come this.constructor points to A inside prototype, if "this" is clearly of type B? I was under illusion that dictionary is traversed from topmost level down prototype chain, but it doesn't seem to be the case here:

```
A=function() {}  
A.prototype.copy=function() {
  return new this.constructor();
}
B=function() {}
B.prototype=new A();

var b=new B();
var bcopy=b.copy();
var cond1=bcopy.constructor==B // false
var cond2=bcopy.constructor==A // true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var b = new B;
b.constructor == A; // true
```

Thus, your `copy()` function is creating a new A. If, however, you add this line:

```
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

...you will get the results you were hoping for.

Comment: But why b.constructor==A? Who assigned it to be A then?

Comment: When you assigned `B.prototype = new A();` you got an object whose `.constructor` property pointed to `A`. All 'instances' created from `B` thus looked up and said, _"You told me that my constructor is A, so that's what I'll report whenever you ask."_ You need to set it back to the correct value since you whacked it.

Comment: Please confirm is the following is true: initially, every function has a prototype property, which points to the object having only one thing in it: constructor method. So, constructor property always comes from prototype. If we redefine prototype, we have to restore constructor to initial value.